# Remove custom email rule from wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, email, privacy

Help a developer i hired not only he didn't finish the job, but also he left a rule that sends him a copy for everyone who sings up on my site i've been trying to remove the  rule from the plugins to no avail I am new to programming, below ill place some images hopefully one can indicate me where such rule could be, i want to mention i am using fluent form and that also he had ftp access only to that specific directory as i didn't fully trusted him.

[image]

[image]

also, there are not custom snippets in the snippets section
also he never had access to cpanel, and the email is sent only from that specific form i belive as it was the only form at the time [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mthGD.png)

[image]

[image]

I can confirm that removing the plugins and removing cache and re-installing the plugins doesn't work but I can officially confirm that the issue only happens when this line is added into fluent form, methods=stripe&fname={inputs.names.first_name}&lname={inputs.names.last_name}&email={inputs.email}&cname={inputs.input_text_1}&acname={inputs.input_text_2}&phone={inputs.numeric-field}&admin_url={submission.id}
Even if only this: *methods=stripe*  is added, still send the email to him that instructions tells the plugin where to find that email address
i tried typing the email address in php my admin and file manager in cpanel but nothing i find only logs at most of the emails sent

Comment: To find where his address is in the code, grep for it on your server: `grep -R jigarn /path/to/wordpress`

Comment: i have shared hosting all i can access through Cpanel is file manager could you give me some indications?
also i noticed that even though i gave him access to a staging copy that i deleted long ago through softaculous, the fluent form link generated still has that version of the staging, here is the link i see to access the fluent form content  ://mysite.com/developer5/wp-admin/admin.php?page=fluent_forms&route=entries&form_id=4#/entries/84?sort_by=DESC&current_page=1&pos=0&type=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: The rule came from within the **theme file editor**, wasn't the plugins.
the developer added his email for notification testing and never removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Fluent forms then you should check the notification rules of that specific form.

- Click on *Settings* of the form you want
- Go to *Settings & Integration*(Top bar) > *Email Notifications* (Sidebar)

There you will see all notification rules for that form, his email is probably there, remove it.

[More info here](https://wpmanageninja.com/docs/fluent-form/how-to-use-wp-fluent-form/email-notification/).

Comment: Thank you for helping, i forgot to add the picture yesterday so just uploaded, anyway when i first noticed the issue that was the first thing i did and removed the email, but the email still being sent, i noticed by pure casuality many months later even after creating other staging copies, also i don't understand why fluent forms would generate a link with an staging address that no longer exist

Comment: Then there are two places to search for it: database and codebase. Cpanel offers a `phpmyadmin` tool, search your database for his email. To search code, go to the file manager, in `wp-content` directory and compress `plugins` and `themes` folders to a zip file. Download that to your computer, and search all files for his email address. You can use Notepad++ for this. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @GeaorgeP. Yesterday i created a new staging & tested that within fluent form there's a line of code that causes the issue within the fluent form settings under Pass Field Data Via Query String here:  methods=stripe&fname={inputs.names.first_name}&lname={inputs.names.last_name}&email={inputs.email}&cname={inputs.input_text_1}&acname={inputs.input_text_2}&phone={inputs.numeric-field}&admin_url={submission.id}

Comment: somehow this code instructs the location of his email,
 i would like to prevent a recall error because of this code. 
Anyway i will try your solution on database

Comment: I've kept in constant communication with the fluent form team, i gave them access to cpanel and they stated that the issue comes from the custom code within the API rule.